# Can't update my db table using Entity Framework and LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a database table and I'm trying to update a cell with a money datatype (decimal) and I'm using LINQ and and Entity Framework.

Unfortunately `Context.SaveChanges();` won't work for some reason.

Here is the table structure

```
Type Amount Machine
Cash 1000   Tablet
```

Here is my code:

```
using (var GC = new GroundCommanderEntities())
{
    PAYMENT_Repo PAYMENTREPO = new PAYMENT_Repo(); 
    var ExistingCashPayment = GC.PAYMENT_Repo
        .Where(Filter => Filter.Type == "Cash" && Filter.Machine == "Tablet").ToList();

    string type = "";
    var amt = 0.00m;

    foreach (var item in ExistingCashPayment)
    {
        type = item.Type;
        amt = item.Amount;
    }

    if (type == cbPaymentType.Text) //a combobox that contains Types 
    {
        PAYMENTREPO.Amount = amt + Convert.ToDecimal(txtTendering.Text);                    
        GC.SaveChanges();

        return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }             
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: @MickyDuncan No it doesn't. When I debug, step into `GC.SaveChanges();` and look into the table, it didn't apply the change.

Comment: You do know in your `foreach` you keep writing over the old values of `amt` and `type`? Is that the problem (Before anyone comments I know strings are immutable)

Comment: @JamieRees I have a foreach loop because I have the ExistingCashPayment  in a List. I can't go through the if statement if the table is null. It is looking for an existing row with Cash type in it. What can you suggest?

Comment: What I mean is you keep overwriting the value of `amt` and `type` everytime in the loop. Really you should make `amt` and `type` a collection.

Comment: Thanks @JamieRees. That made more sense. I learned something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here:

Most importantly, `PAYMENTREPO` is a new instance - its not from the db context, so changing values on it has no effect. You need to add it before saving changes:

```
PAYMENTREPO.Amount = amt + Convert.ToDecimal(txtTendering.Text);                    
GC.PAYMENTREPOs.Add(PAYMENTREPO);
GC.SaveChanges();
```

Second, which won't cause the complete fail to update, but will cause the code to do things other than you expect:

```
foreach (var item in ExistingCashPayment)
{
    type = item.Type;
    amt = item.Amount;
}
```

This loop will leave `type` and `amt` set to the last value in the ExistingCashPayment list, rather than some sort of accumulation of the contents of that list, which would be the desired behaviour implied by having the loop there in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like GC is your DbContext. If so you need to add the state of the object is modified as follows...

db.Entry(obj).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
db.SaveChanges();

This should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a **new entity** like you do, you must **add** it to the context before calling `SaveChanges()`:

```
using (var GC = new GroundCommanderEntities())
{
    PAYMENT_Repo PAYMENTREPO = new PAYMENT_Repo(); 
    var ExistingCashPayment = GC.PAYMENT_Repo
        .Where(Filter => Filter.Type == "Cash" && Filter.Machine == "Tablet").ToList();

    string type = "";
    var amt = 0.00m;

    foreach (var item in ExistingCashPayment)
    {
        type = item.Type;
        amt = item.Amount;
    }

    if (type == cbPaymentType.Text) //a combobox that contains Types 
    {
        PAYMENTREPO.Amount = amt + Convert.ToDecimal(txtTendering.Text);                    

        // add your NEW entity to the context!
        // depending on which exact version of EF you're using, this
        // might be called `.Add()` or `.AddObject()`
        // Also, the name "PAYMENTREPOs" is just a guess - it might be 
        // different in your concrete case - adapt as needed!
        GC.PAYMENTREPOs.Add(PAYMENTREPO);

        GC.SaveChanges();

        return true;
     }
     else
     {
         return false;
     }             
}
```

Comment: I have another function that does the adding. to the PAYMENT_Repo table. I need not to add another row but rather add the Amount when it is existing in the table.

Comment: @JoshuaMasangcay: in that case, you must **load** (fetch) the existing row from the context first - before updating it! And then call `.SaveChanges()` after the changes are applied